# Adding Delay to title change on Blur JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to add a few seconds delay before the title change but can't seem to get it to work. I believe it involves 'setTimeout', but can't quite figure it out.

```js
$(function() {
          var pageTitle = $('title').text();
        $(window).blur(function () {
          $('title').text(`WAIT! COME BACK! ${pageTitle}`)
        });
        $(window).focus(function() {
          $('title').text(pageTitle);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

  var pageTitle = $('title').text();
  $(window).blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('title').text(`WAIT! COME BACK! ${pageTitle}`);
    }, 3000);
  });
  $(window).focus(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('title').text(pageTitle);
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

Comment: this works well with the time however it only changes when you leave the browser, not when you just switch tab

Answer (score 0):

Try using the delay() function:

```js
$(function() {
          var pageTitle = $('title').text();
        $(window).delay(800).blur(function () {
          $('title').text(`WAIT! COME BACK! ${pageTitle}`)
        });
        $(window).focus(function() {
          $('title').text(pageTitle);
        });
      });
```

Comment: This is what I initially tried however it didn't apply the delay. everything still works but the change takes place instantly